# CellForRowAt indexPath not being called iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a `tableView` programatically in a `ViewController`, however when I load the `ViewController` the function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called.

I have look at many suggestions on StackOverflow, but none of the helped resolve the issue. Could some one please guide me where I am going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AlgoliaSearch

class ReportVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, DrugMoleculesTVCProtocol {

    // FOR SCREEN DIMENSIONS
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    var screenWidth: CGFloat
    var screenHeight: CGFloat
    var saveButton : UIBarButtonItem?
    var cancelButton: UIBarButtonItem?

    // For Table view
    var tableView    : UITableView     = UITableView()
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var tableViewCell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
    var selectedObjectsArray: Array = [Any]()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        screenHeight = screenSize.height
        screenWidth = screenSize.width
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setting buttons for the Nav Bar
        saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.save, target: self, action: #selector(save))
        cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancel))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = saveButton
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = cancelButton
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = [] // This ensures that the views dont go below the navigation bar


        // ADDING LABELS AND TEXT VIEWS
        let myObservationsLabel : UILabel =  {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "My Observations"
            return label
        }()

        let myObservationsTextView : UITextView = {
           let textView = UITextView()
           textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
           textView.font?.withSize(22.0)
           return textView
        }()


        let myLabel : UILabel =  {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "Standard"
            return label
        }()

        let addButton : UIButton =  {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addItems), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }()

        let myTextField : UITextField = {
            let textField = UITextField()
            textField.placeholder = "Name"
            return textField
        }()


        let nextStepsLabel : UILabel =  {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "Next Steps"
            return label
        }()

        // Add textView for Next steps
        let nextStepsTextView : UITextView = {
            let textView = UITextView()
            textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            textView.font?.withSize(22.0)
            return textView
        }()

        self.view.addSubview(myObservationsLabel)
        self.view.addSubview(myObservationsTextView)
        self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
        self.view.addSubview(addButton)


        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        // Setting datasource and Delegate for TableView
        tableView.delegate      =   self
        tableView.dataSource    =   self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

        self.view.addSubview(myTextField)
        self.view.addSubview(nextStepsLabel)
        self.view.addSubview(nextStepsTextView)

        // Disabling Auto Constraints to set constraints manually
        myObservationsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints    = false
        myObservationsTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints                = false
        addButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints              = false
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints              = false
        myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints            = false
        nextStepsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints         = false
        nextStepsTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints      = false

        // Adding views to dictionary
        let viewsDict = [
            "myObservationsLabel"    : myObservationsLabel,
            "myObservationsTextView" : myObservationsTextView,
            "myLabel"                : myLabel,
            "addButton"              : addButton,
            "tableView"              : tableView,
            "myTextField"            : myTextField,
            "nextStepsLabel"         : nextStepsLabel,
            "nextStepsTextView"      : nextStepsTextView
        ]

        // Setting Constraints to the views in Dictionary
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-20-[myObservationsLabel(25)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[myObservationsLabel]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        // Setting constraints for myObservationsTextView
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[myObservationsLabel]-10-[myObservationsTextView(100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[myObservationsTextView]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        // Setting constraints for nextStepsLabel
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[myObservationsTextView]-10-[nextStepsLabel(25)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[nextStepsLabel]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        // Setting constraints for nextStepsTextView
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[nextStepsLabel]-10-[nextStepsTextView(100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[nextStepsTextView]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        // Setting constraints for myLabel
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[nextStepsTextView]-10-[myLabel(25)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[myLabel]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        // Setting constraints for addButton
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[nextStepsTextView]-10-[addButton(25)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[addButton]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        // Setting constraints for myTextField
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[addButton]-10-[myTextField(25)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[myTextField]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

        // Setting constraints for  Table view
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[myTextField]-10-[tableView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[tableView]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func save(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        print("Clicked save button")
    }

    func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        print("Clicked cancel button")
    }

    func addItems(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("addItems Button Clicked")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSearchTable", sender: self)
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension ReportVC {

    func setSelectedDrugMolecules(_ valueSent: [Any]){
        print("setSelectedDrugMolecules func called")
        self.selectedObjectsArray = valueSent
        print("self.selectedObjectsArray in func: \(self.selectedObjectsArray)")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSearchTable" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! DrugMoleculesTVC
            vc.selectedObjectsArray = self.selectedObjectsArray
            vc.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("table view loaded in numberOfSections")
        return 1
    }


    // Return the number of rows for each section in your static table

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("printing numberOfRowsInSection:\(selectedObjectsArray.count)")
        return 10
    }

    // Return the row for the corresponding section and row

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("table view loaded in cellForRowAt")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
        return cell
    }

    // Customize the section headings for each section
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch(section) {
        case 0: return "Drug Name"
        default: fatalError("Unknown section")
        }
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let row     = indexPath.row
        let section = indexPath.section

        if section == 0 && row == 0 {
            //The user has clicked on qualification cell
            print("TableView Section 0 Row 1 cell has been clicked")
        }
        else if section == 0 && row == 1 {
            // The user has clicked on languages spoken cell
            print("TableView Section 0 Row 2 cell has been clicked")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `selectedObjectsArray`  empty when call `numberOfRowsInSection` ? and the `return 10` below is invalid because you have returned the `selectedObjectsArray.count`.

Comment: Did you forget to set delegate and datasource ?  tableView.delegate = self and for datasource as well?

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson I have set them in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson he does. Scroll to the middle section of the code

Comment: @a_tuo yes, it is empty on load.

Comment: It might not be related but try declaring your extension as the one that conforms to the protocol -> extension ReportVC: UITableViewDelegate

Comment: have u tried putting debugger on any other delegate methods other than cellforrow AtIndexPath.

Answer (score 2):

The dataSource `selectedObjectsArray` is empty when you call ç. When number of rows in section is 0, tableView would not call `cellForRowAt`.

So, you should put something into `selectedObjectsArray` before call `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Or, when you have set `selectedObjectsArray`, call `tableView.reloadView`.

The fast way, you can just `return 10(fixed number)` in `numberOfRowsInSection` to see whether UI works.

Answer (score 1):

The real culprit was that I missed a **`|`** while setting a Vertical constraint for my TableView `V:[myTextField]-10-[tableView]|`.

```
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[myTextField]-10-[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
```

Without all of your input, I wouldn't be able to figure it out, Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As I could get from your get code, you have `datasource` and `delegate` of `UITableView` properly. `ReloadData` is also there. `CGRect.Zero` might be the real culprit. As the frame is not defined, TableView is not drawn, hence its datasource methods are not called.

As an developer you should try separating your designing and logic part. Prefer creating all view and constraints in Storyboard / Xib whichever u free. It cleans the code and make it understandable. 
Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

did you tried changing frame of tableView added you are using

```
 tableView = `UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)`
```

Try giving some frame value to it instead of CGRect.zero(0,0,0,0) and try using

```
 CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
```